# Rails looking for wrong method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a column named _SOMETHING as part of an object created with rails g scaffold, say: `rails g scaffold Person _SOMETHING:string`

In the create method, when doing @person.save, an error pops up saying that it doesn't find method `something`(no underscore and lowercases).

Why is it looking for a method with that name?

I patched it by creating

```
def something
   true
end
```

in my Person model. I am sure that's not the correct way to solve this.
Using Ruby 2.2.2, Rails 4.2.1

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the reason behind the decision not to follow Rails naming conventions?

Comment: I am building a sort of GUI for a project using Shinken. Shinken can pull custom variables by calling them _SOMETHING. It also has a MySQL module to pull the configuration form.

Comment: Do you have ```attr_accessor :_something``` in your model ? I am not sure if active record is capable to create the getter and the setter associated to your _something field.
Is your field named correctly in your database ?
Can you paste your model in your question ?

Comment: I don't want to post it, it was a stupid silly mistake. Turns out I had a validation and I spelled the column the wrong way. Spelled it right on the validation and hooray, it worked.

Thanks spickermann and jiop for your time and attention with this!!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the model had a validation where I misspelled the column name, failing each time. Changed the name to `_SOMETHING` and it worked.

Thank you all for your attention to this silly issue